# Hibernate Search - MySQL error too many joins with Joined Inheritance model

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-search

I've just encountered the following MySQL error in my web app

```
Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join
```

This is occurring when performing a Hibernate Search (version 5.5.2) query and I'm not entirely sure why that many joins are required. Here is a simplified example of my entity model:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Profile {
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    RelatedEntityOne joinOne;
}

@Indexed
@Entity
public class BusinessProfile extends Profile {
    @ManyToOne
    RelatedEntityTwo joinTwo;
}

@Indexed
@Entity
public class UserProfile extends Profile {
    @ManyToOne
    RelatedEntityThree joinThree;
}
```

Here is the code that performs the query

```
FullTextEntityManager ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = ftem.createFullTextQuery(myQuery, UserProfile.class);
List result = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

And here is an example of the generated SQL

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Profile root 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BusinessProfile join_1 ON root.id = join_1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserProfile join_2 ON root.id = join_2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN RelatedEntityOne join_3 ON root.x = join_3.x
LEFT OUTER JOIN RelatedEntityTwo join_4 ON join_1.x = join_4.x
LEFT OUTER JOIN RelatedEntityThree join_5 ON join_2.x = join_5.x
WHERE root.id IN (...)
```

So in this simplified example there are 5 joins. Which would make sense if I was performing a query on the parent class `Profile`. However I've passed the child class `UserProfile` to the `createFullTextQuery` method, so I would expect the generated SQL to look more like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM UserProfile root 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Profile join_1 ON root.id = join_1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN RelatedEntityOne join_2 ON join_1.x = join_2.x
LEFT OUTER JOIN RelatedEntityThree join_3 ON root.x = join_3.x
WHERE root.id IN (...)
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with Hibernate, Hibernate Search, my own code, or if there is no issue and everything is behaving as intended. I don't see any reason for it to be joining the sibling tables given that we've identified which child table to use.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, we didn't think of optimising for deep inheritance but clearly that's a good idea! Guillaume's patch below looks great, we'll merge it soon and publish a nightly build which you can try.

Comment: The patch is merged, CI needs to finish testing and will release a nightly build in approximately 2 hours. If you'd like to try it out make sure you enable the JBoss Maven repository to be able to download it, e.g. use https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/settings-example.xml

Comment: Thanks @Sanne and Guillaume for patching it so quickly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm it's a bug in Hibernate Search. Here is the JIRA I just created: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2301 .

I already wrote a fix but I have to go and doesn't have the time to clean it up; I'll post a PR later today.

Thanks for spotting this issue!

**UPDATE** we fixed it in 5.5.4.Final: http://in.relation.to/2016/06/29/Polishing-Polishing-And-More-Polishing-Hibernate-Search-5-5-4-Final/